# What is the best way to store authentication (login) in a system when a user has been authenticated using shadow in Linux with C++

Tags: c++, linux, authentication, security, shadow

I have a project called [`kos`](https://ari-web.xyz/gh/kos) and it's a simple SUID tool,
recently as a lot of people in private have been asking
me I added authentication storing/remembering,
but it's not that good

So what happens basically is:

- Verify that the user has entered the correct password
- If the password is correct set the `temp_validate_user` variable to `true` and `temp_validate_user_id` to the authenticated user's ID (e.g. `1000`)
- In the `run_command` function, after setting the appropriate IDs (uid, euid, gid and egid) do:

  - If the `last modified` timestamp is less than the set max ammount, remove `/var/kos/<user id>`
  - Else if `temp_validate_user` is still set make sure `/var/kos` exists, if not make it then make a file called `/var/kos/<user id>` (e.g. `/var/kos/1000`)

To put it simply we just store a file called `/var/kos/<user id>` and then check if its last modified timestamp is less than the max ammount

But we got a problem

Even though the dir is root-only with kos you can
get root and if you verify once you can do this:

```bash
while true; do echo | kos touch "/var/kos/$(id -u)"; done
```

And when the user authenticates the file will be
be updated all the time meaning you can have infinite
root bypass

So the question is, is there ANY better way to do this,
I really need to find a better way because as more of the
time passes I keep getting more and more worried about
it and I can't think of anything

Oh and if it wasn't clear already, I don't want to
use PAM or anything else other than pure C or C++

Related commits and lines of code:

- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/commit/cbcc1346d76b0c47bb4658a1b650de11f74a2727
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/config.h#L62
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/macros.hpp#L40
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/main.cpp#L37
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/main.cpp#L46
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/main.cpp#L23
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/main.cpp#L175
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/blob/main/src/main.cpp#L185
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/commit/f8c4e79e798c0ffaa15df9d1d77fb91b54e61599
- https://github.com/TruncatedDinosour/kos/commit/9ee54bbd01281016d1170c37b0a6cd23433b1227

Thanks for the answers in advance :)

### Questions and answers

- What's your goal?

> Store that the user has logged in for x ammount of seconds
> then if x seconds have passed invalidate it,
> but until x seconds hasn't passed don't ask the
> specific logged in user to enter their password

Comment: It's such a complicated situation, I was thinking maybe I should ship a seperate program to start at system init which sets up a UNIX socket but then as I started doing it I realised 'oh anyone can send data to it, thats a stupid idea' lol, well, I am out of ideas for now

Comment: Isn't that similar to [what `sudo` does](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37299/how-does-sudo-remember-you-already-entered-roots-password)? The implementation of `sudo` should be open source.

Comment: Do you really think someone will read 10 git commits and then write an answer? I won't.

Comment: @ThomasWeller you don't have to read anything, just in case you want, but ah, okay, i thought there was a better way, guess not? Thanks for the answer, could you actually post it as an answer though so I could give you the checkmark? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ThomasWeller sudo does the same thing, meaning it's secure
enough, I dropped the terms on the dir from 744 to 711 and file
perms from 744 to 600

Thank you @ThomasWeller once again

Comment: No, wait, I didn't say that sudo does the same thing. It just remembers that you have entered the password and you can run it again without the need of entering a password. I suggested to **read the source code of the `sudo` implementation.**

Comment: @ThomasWeller ah, well, lemme see

Comment: @ThomasWeller as sudo's source code is huggeee I'm unable to really navigate it, but, from what I saw it's around the same (if you compile it with no PAM). plus it seems like my dir from over a year ago when i had sudo has somewhat same structure so yeah, anyway, thanks :)